# How to make NVDA and JAWS always read insertions in aria decorated div

Tags: html, wai-aria, screen-readers

I have a PRE tag that will be filled with many spans as time goes on.

This will be the output of a textual game.
I need the screen readers to read every addition to this element.

```
<pre id="winOutput" role="region" aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions" class="outputText"></pre>
```

The above is what I tried.
NVDA reads nothing (except when hovering the lines with the mouse).
But automatic javascript additions are not being read.

From what I understand **aria-live="assertive" aria-relevant="additions"** is what I need but it does not work.
To specify: I need to read additions, the previous text will remain inside (and from time to time old lines will be removed).

Can somebody explain what is needed here?
If a game for visually impaired people is not being read at all it does not work...

Trying in Chrome and Edge

Edit: if I add **aria-atomic** then NVDA reads every time there is an addition but it reads every time from the START/Everything.

Answer (score 0):

It might be because the definition of "additions" for `aria-relevant` says (**emphasis** mine):

> Element **nodes** are added to the accessibility tree within the live
> region.

If I read that literally, then you have to add a new DOM element for "additions" to be announced.  But it sounds like you are just adding text to the `<pre>` and not new nodes.  If so, then "text" should be the value for `aria-relevant`.

I typically don't specify `aria-relevant` and use the default of "additions text".  If you will be adding nodes/children to the `<pre>` and you **don't** want them announced, then using "text" will prevent nodes from being announced.  But it's rare that both nodes and text are being added to an element and both are not desired to be announced.  I would start with a simple live region first and see how it sounds.

```
<pre id="winOutput" role="region" aria-live="polite" class="outputText"></pre>
```

BTW, I would use `aria-live="polite"` (as shown above) because it's rare that an announcement is so important that it needs "assertive".  Using "assertive" [can blow away](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) any pending screen reader announcements.

> User agents or assistive technologies MAY choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs.

`aria-atomic` just says whether to announce *just* the change or the entire text.  It's handy for things like a countdown timer where the text changes from "You have 60 seconds" to "You have 50 seconds".  *Without* `aria-atomic`, the screen reader announces "*You have 60 seconds*" for the first change and then just "*50*" for the second change (because "50" is all that changed in the sentence).  *With* `aria-atomic="true"`, the second change would announce as "*You have 50 seconds*".

**Update:**
To answer a few questions from the comments section.

If you are depending on "assertive" to clear pending announcements, go back to the quote I had earlier that says:

> User agents or assistive technologies MAY choose to clear queued changes when an assertive change occurs

The "MAY" is uppercased in the spec.  I didn't add that emphasis.  So this says pending announcements **might** be cleared or they might not.  It's up to the browser and/or screen reader.  There's no guarantee they'll be cleared so you can't rely on this behavior.

Regarding `role="log"`, the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#log) says

> Elements with the role `log` have an implicit `aria-live` value of polite.

So if you have both `role="log"` *and* `aria-live="assertive"`, then it's undetermined what behavior you'll get.  You have competing `aria-live` values.

If you have `role="alert"` and `aria-live="assertive"`, then the `aria-live` is superfluous.  You're already getting that setting with alert.

If you specify any kind of `role` that is **not** a live region (ie, not alert, log, or status), then it should not affect whether `aria-live` is honored.  But you have to read the [spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/wai-aria/#aria-live) for `aria-live` pretty carefully.  There are lots of caveats that say what the user agent or assistive technology *should* do but "should" is not a requirement.  It may or may not work like you want it to.  The spec even says the users screen reader settings might affect how aria-live works.

Regarding focus, it does **not** have to be in the live region in order for the change to be announced.  That's the great thing about live regions.  They'll announce anytime a change is made regardless of where the focus is.  The only time the focus has to be in the live region is if `aria-live="off"` is set.

So in your case, your sample code looks correct (now that you confirmed you are adding DOM elements to the `<pre>`).  I would recommend testing on a few different browsers (firefox, chrome, safari) and try with a few different screen readers (jaws, nvda, voiceover) to see if any of them are behaving like you wish.

Comment: I am adding <Span>s to the <pre>.
I'm not sure I follow tough.
I tried with assertive because the new added span needs to be read and it need to interrupt the reading of the previous one. This is the game and the last output is the most important. The previous can be read by hovering above if you miss something.

Comment: Another thing I don't understand is the "role". If I put role="log" nothing is read. If I put region, it reads at the start, but no additional additions are read. If I put role="alert" it reads everytime from the start... It seems that role overrrides aria-relevant?

I simply need it to read EVERY TIME when new spans are added by interrupting the previous thing and reading only the newly added spans. Is there some role that matches this kind of behaviro? role="gameoutput" or similar :D

It seems like a pretty straightforward usecase: read everytime what is added to the screen.

Comment: perhaps I got why is it behaving weird. If the focus is not inside the PRE then it does not read. But i need to have the focus in the input element, but still have the putput read when it is updated.